# Laravel: which is better dispatching single job for multiple emails or multiple jobs for each email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a task in which I have to send thousands of emails in laravel. My question is that is it better to create a single job that sends email to all emails or creating a job that sends email to single email and dispatch it multiple times?

Comment: You are asking for non-coding question and also asking for opinion. You need to have some difficulties like when I tried to do it with one job I have problem x, should I refactor, or does it perform better than multiple jobs? You might want to improve the question.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Thanks for your answer. I asked this question because I was in a dilemma and wanted to start my work the right way and for me it was a difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 1millions of emails, your job may run out of memory or time out quickly. Its optimal to spread sending each email in their own process for two reasons:

1. There's less possibility of memory exhaustion and time out
2. If there's a failure e.g wrong email, network failure etc. you can isolate failed email with failed job and perform necessary actions on them.